# Using pandas to count user orders that happen within the hour from start time with irregular time interval

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, rolling-computation

Let's say we have this

```
| eventdatetime       | orderid | userid |
| 2019-12-27 03:06:50 | 1       |  100   |
| 2019-12-27 04:12:50 | 2       |  20    |
| 2019-12-27 05:06:58 | 3       |  140   |
| 2019-12-29 03:00:10 | 4       |  104   |
```

I tried using rolling groupby e.g. `df.groupby('userid').rolling('1h').orderid.count()` but it's not working because it's looking backwards 1 hour and roll it up to the current datetime in the row. It doesn't look forward to check if there is order in the next 1 hour if I use rolling.

For e.g. if look at orderid 2, the datetime is 04:12:50, so I want to count the number of orders inclusive 1 hour from this time which is until 05:12:50. In other words counting how many orders placed by user from 04:12:50 to 05:12:50 - in this case it's 2 but rolling will give me 1 since it looks from 03:12:50 to 04:12:50.

Is there any function in pandas that can do this or did I understand rolling wrongly?

**Edit 1**
Initially I thought I can just use some columns but somehow it doesn't work with the raw columns so I'm adding all in the mix.

We have here the datetime index and 3 id columns

```
                    | orderid           shopid      userid
event_time          
2019-12-31 13:13:34 | 31468414075366    214432425   1134243
2019-12-31 23:32:03 | 31505523761333    214432425   1134243
2019-12-31 23:45:49 | 31506349293329    214432425   52594422
2019-12-31 23:46:35 | 31506394434087    214432425   52594422
```

Using Roy2012's solution 
but added join condition with orderid because i need the orderid later on rather than just time

```
hour_ends = pd.DataFrame({'hour_start': df.index, 
        'orderid': df.orderid.values
    }, index=df.index + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

t = pd.merge(df, hour_ends, on='orderid', left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

gives me

```
                     orderid            shopid        userid        event_start
event_time              
2019-12-31 13:13:34 | 31468414075366    214432425.0 | 1134243.0   | NaT
2019-12-31 14:13:34 | 31468414075366    NaN         | NaN         |2019-12-31 13:13:34
2019-12-31 23:32:03 | 31505523761333    214432425.0 | 1134243.0   | NaT
2019-12-31 23:45:49 | 31506349293329    214432425.0 | 52594422.0  | NaT
2019-12-31 23:46:35 | 31506394434087    214432425.0 | 52594422.0  | NaT
2020-01-01 00:32:03 | 31505523761333    NaN         | NaN         | 2019-12-31 23:32:03
2020-01-01 00:45:49 | 31506349293329    NaN         | NaN         | 2019-12-31 23:45:49
2020-01-01 00:46:35 | 31506394434087    NaN         | NaN         | 2019-12-31 23:46:35
```

then adding this to roll forward

```
t["rolling_count"] = t.rolling("1h", closed="both").count()["orderid"]
t.reset_index()[['event_start', 'orderid', 'rolling_count']].dropna()
```

gives this result which doesn't tally

```
event_start         | orderid         | rolling_count
2019-12-31 13:13:34 | 31468414075366  | 2.0
2019-12-31 23:32:03 | 31505523761333  | 4.0
2019-12-31 23:45:49 | 31506349293329  | 4.0
2019-12-31 23:46:35 | 31506394434087  | 4.0
```

i'm expecting the results to be something like

```
event_start         | orderid         | rolling_count
2019-12-31 13:13:34 | 31468414075366  | 1.0
2019-12-31 23:32:03 | 31505523761333  | 3.0
2019-12-31 23:45:49 | 31506349293329  | 2.0
2019-12-31 23:46:35 | 31506394434087  | 1.0
```

since orderid 31468414075366 in 1 hour from 13:13 has only 1 order, 31505523761333 in 1 hour from 23:32 to 00:32 has total 3 orders, etc.

Comment: `df.rolling('1h')['userid'].count()` will give you the result, why group on user id?

Comment: Good catch. I meant orderid count. Just fixed that. I'm counting the orders made by user in that 1 hour time frame. not counting users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution. It's based on the idea of adding artificial rows one hour after the 'real' rows. We'll run the rolling count, get the results, and then match them back to the original times. Here's the code, broken into several steps for clarity.

```
import datetime

# Create a dataframe with 1 hour time windows
hour_ends = pd.DataFrame({"hour_start":  df.index}, 
                         index = df.index + datetime.timedelta(hours=1))

# merge the original dataframe and the new one. 
t = pd.merge(df, hour_ends, left_index=True, right_index=True, how = "outer")

# do the rolling count. 
t["rolling_count"] = t.rolling("1h", closed="both").count()["orderid"]

# match the results back to the starting time. 
res = t.reset_index()[["hour_start", "rolling_count"]].dropna()
print (res)
```

The result is:

```
           hour_start  rolling_count
1 2019-12-27 03:06:50            1.0
4 2019-12-27 04:12:50            2.0
5 2019-12-27 05:06:58            1.0
7 2019-12-29 03:00:10            1.0
```

Comment: what does closed="both" mean? is that necessary?

Comment: It means that the interval is closed on both sides. It’s needed - or it won’t count Ethel event that occurred exactly an hour before that time stamp.

Comment: Did it answer your question? If so, it would be great if you could mark it as an answer for future generations.

Comment: do you know why I can't reverse my df i.e. df.iloc[::-1] and apply rolling?

Comment: Interesting idea. My understanding is that the index is "required to be monotonic" - meaning, the time should move forward. Regardless, it would be nice to know if it answers your question or not.

Comment: i tried the artificial rows but somehow it doesn't show the correct results. I've updated the post. Is it because i added in the orderid column?

Comment: If I had to guess - yes. Did you try the original solution and check if it produces the correct results?

Comment: yes it does, but purely match back on time might be an issue because the time is not unique. there could be different order in the same time. that's why i added the unique order id

Comment: if two orders start at the exact same time, it means that their rolling count would be identical - doesn't it?

Comment: that makes sense. but i have several shops. my initial thought was to have a loop to run through this for every shop i have. but do u think is possible for me to group by the shopid and run the same code?

Comment: I see no reason why not. Just group by shop number, and then do the whole rolling thing. I think that's possible.